# ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure() Behavior

Tags: powershell

I am trying to figure out how ScriptBlock.GetNewClosure() works. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421964/looping-through-controls-in-wpf-powershell) thread (see Stej's answer) I have this code:

```
$i = 1
$block1 = 
{
    $i
}

$i = 2
$block2 = 
{
    $i
}

$i = 3
$block3 = 
{
    $i
}


& $block1
& $block2
& $block3
```

The output is:

```
3
3
3
```

which is expected, because when the ScriptBlocks are executed the current $i value is used. This can be changed using GetNewClosure():

```
$i = 1
$block1 = 
{
    $i
}.GetNewClosure()

$i = 2
$block2 = 
{
    $i
}.GetNewClosure()

$i = 3
$block3 = 
{
    $i
}.GetNewClosure()


& $block1
& $block2
& $block3
```

This time the output is:

```
1
2
3
```

This is good, but when I try to star the ScriptBlocks as jobs:

```
$i = 1
$block1 = 
{
    $i
}.GetNewClosure()

$i = 2
$block2 = 
{
    $i
}.GetNewClosure()

$i = 3
$block3 = 
{
    $i
}.GetNewClosure()


$job1 = Start-Job $block1
$job1 | Wait-Job 
$job1 | Receive-Job

$job2 = Start-Job $block2
$job2 | Wait-Job 
$job2 | Receive-Job

$job3 = Start-Job $block3
$job3 | Wait-Job 
$job3 | Receive-Job
```

There is no output. Searching for an answer, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415871/new-closure-on-scriptblock) thread, where x0n says that jobs are executed in a dynamic module. Modules have isolated sessionstate, and share access to globals. PowerShell closures only work within the same sessionstate / scope chain

Does this mean that $i is not accessible from jobs? When I test its value:

```
$i = 1
$block1 = 
{
    $i -eq $null
}.GetNewClosure()

$i = 2
$block2 = 
{
    $i -eq $null
}.GetNewClosure()

$i = 3
$block3 = 
{
    $i -eq $null
}.GetNewClosure()


$job1 = Start-Job $block1
$job1 | Wait-Job 
$job1 | Receive-Job

$job2 = Start-Job $block2
$job2 | Wait-Job 
$job2 | Receive-Job

$job3 = Start-Job $block3
$job3 | Wait-Job 
$job3 | Receive-Job
```

$ is equal to null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it means that `$i` is not accessible from jobs in this way. Unfortunately. So, use another way: for example, `param` in a script block to be invoked as a job and `ArgumentList` parameter of `Start-Job`:

```
$i = 42
$block1 =
{
    param($i)
    $i * 2
}

$job1 = Start-Job $block1 -ArgumentList $i
$job1 | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Output:

```
84
```

P.S. It is reported that `GetNewClosure` also does not work with `Register-ObjectEvent`:
https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/541754/getnewclosure-doesnt-work-on-register-objectevent

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is this behavior documented by Microsoft?

Comment: Well, I would say it is a legal feature but the documentation about it might be better. BTW, instead of `param` in a script block you can just use `$args`.

Answer (score -3):

```
$i = 1
$block1 =  {"block 1 is $using:i" }.GetNewClosure()

$i = 2
$block2 = { "block 2 is $using:i" }.GetNewClosure()

$job1 = Start-Job $block1
$job1 | Wait-Job 
$job1 | Receive-Job

$job2 = Start-Job $block2
$job2 | Wait-Job 
$job2 | Receive-Job
```

http://www.powertheshell.com/closure/