# How to use .GetNewClosure() with the -Action value for an EngineEvent

Tags: powershell, closures

```
& { 
    $action = & { $y = 100
        return { write-host "Value: $y" }.getnewclosure()
    }

    [void] (register-engineevent -sourcei "foo" -action $action)
    [void] (new-event -sourcei "foo")
}
```

The code above prints `Value:`, while I'd expect it to print `Value: 100`. Is something missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The engine is calling `GetNewClosure()` on it, which is a better thing for it to do than not.

When I ran the above, I got an output of only `Value:`, but then I globally declared `$y = 25` and ran `[void](new-event -sourcei 'foo')` again, the output was `Value: 25`. Then I changed its value again, `$y = 38`, and ran the event again: `Value: 38`.

If what you want is to bake in the value of `$y` at the time you create the action, one way to do that is to create the scriptblock in such a way that the value of `$y` becomes a literal or part of a literal:

```
$action = &{ $y = 100
    return (invoke-expression "{write-host 'Value: $y'}")
}
```

This first parses the string to insert the value, so `Invoke-Expression` ends up doing the equivalent of this:

```
{write-host 'Value: 100'}
```

I'm not sure if there are any other ways to bake in the value other than composing the entire content of the scriptblock in a string and passing it through `Invoke-Expression`.

---

In response to your comment, further explanation of closures:

```
> $action100 = &{$y = 100; return {write-host "Value: $y"}.GetNewClosure()}
> &$action100
Value: 100
```

That's the result you expect, and that's what you get, because the scriptblock is still "closed" around the value of `$y` in the scope where `GetNewClosure()` was called.

```
> $y = 25
> &$action100
Value: 100
```

Still closed around the `$y` that is `100`.

```
> $action25 = $action100.GetNewClosure()
> &$action25
Value: 25
```

This produces a new scriptblock that encloses variables in the current scope. It makes it re-evaluate what `$y` is in that scriptblock, and in this context, `$y` is now 25.

```
> $y = 38
> &$action100
Value: 100

> &$action25
Value: 25

> &($action100.GetNewClosure())
Value: 38
```

At this point, because `$y` is declared globally now, when you call `New-Event` it will use `GetNewClosure()` and re-evaluate `$y` to `38`, and print `Value: 38`. You've been getting `Value:` because in the context where the engine events call `GetNewClosure()` the variable `$y` is not defined, so `"Value: $y"` becomes `"Value: "`.

Comment: If you take the `$action` part above alone and run in in the console, you do get the expected result. That's what's confusing me. I don't understand why it should be different to calling `Register-EngineEvent`.

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4058721/22211) also goes over some simple examples of how `GetNewClosure()` changes things.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you. And the linked post helped me understand why wrapping the `-Action` in additional braces won't help.